# addOverlay and delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, mkmapview

Trying to draw an overlay Polygon on a map but the delegate method `- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay` is never called...

```
-(void)displayArea:(NSArray *)points{

   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[6]  ={
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.64,7.59),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.62,7.50),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.57,7.45),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.51,7.57),
         CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.61,7.66),
         CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.64,7.59),
    };

    MKPolygon * polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:6];

    [self.myMap addOverlay:polygon level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay{

    NSLog(@"mapview");


    return nil;
}
```

The log mapView is never returned and the view is connected correctly to the delegate (viewController).

Really cannot understand....

Screenshot of outlets:

[image]

Comment: 100% sure `myMap.delegate` is this VC? If you add `[self.myMap setDelegate:self]` above adding the overlay you will 100% rule that out...

Comment: I have added [self.myMap setDelegate:self]; just before [self.myMap addOverlay... but it does not work.

Comment: Just before the addOverlay line, put `NSLog(@"self.myMap=%@", self.myMap);` and see what it says.  If it says (null), then the map's outlet is not connected in Interface Builder (this is separate from the delegate outlet).

Comment: Hey Anna yes indeed it returns null, but I have connected the outlet with IB ... Can you please enlighten me about what should I do?

Comment: The strange thing is that the delegate method - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
     NSLog(@"test");
    
} is always correctly called...

Comment: The delegate outlet is separate from the MKMapView IBOutlet.  They are two separate things.  Add a link to a screenshot showing your outlet connections.

Comment: thank you Anna here we go: http://www.airbusguru.com/andrea/screen1.png

Comment: Why is the "view" also connected to the map view?  Only myMap should be connected to "Map View".

Comment: Fixed now view is connected only to view but still NSLog returns nil.... and the delegate is not called.... however this delegate  - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{ NSLog(@"test"); } is called correctly...

Comment: Solved I was callsign the delegate before the NIB was loaded so... No outlet yet.